# Teams silent authentication with keyclock

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, microsoft-teams

I got the token from the active directory by using teams tab silent authantication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad

Now how do I get that token signed by keyclock identity provider

Comment: first, you need to get a token then redirect to oidc URL I am able to solve it by using OIDC sso configuration in keyclok that is working fine

Answer (score 1):

For any OAuth provider you can follow the steps mentioned in the [Tab Authentication documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab). Instead of redirecting to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` you can redirect to your auth provider to complete the login flow.

1. Open the auth pop-up window using SDK method.

   ```
   microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
    url: window.location.origin + "/tab-auth/start-page",
    width: 600,
    height: 535,
    successCallback: function (result) {
        getUserProfile(result.accessToken);
    },
    failureCallback: function (reason) {
        handleAuthError(reason);
    }
   ```

   });
2. Redirect user to Authentication provider login page in `/tab-auth/start-page`

   ```
    let authorizeEndpoint = "Your OAth provider page link here";
    window.location.assign(authorizeEndpoint);
   ```
3. User now would be redirect to complete the login.
4. Once the Login is complete and you receive the token you need to call `microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess()` to complete the login flow (This closes the login pop-up).

Please let us know if you are facing any issues.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the help I am able to complete it by using OIDC sso that is working directly